# Deleting index in elasticsearch

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I want to delete an entire index of elastic search which i had created using the following code in python notebook.

```
es.index(index='para', doc_type='people', id=1, body={
    "name":"Farid ullah",
    "height":"160",
    "age":"23",
    "gender":"male",
    "date of birth":"04/02/1994",
    "Qualification":"BS in Software engineering"

})
```

the delete command is as follows,

`es.delete(index='para', doc_type='people')`,
but I get the following error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-26c24345ae23> in <module>()
----> 1 es.delete(index='para', doc_type='people')

C:\Users\Farid ullah\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client\utils.py in _wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
     71                 if p in kwargs:
     72                     params[p] = kwargs.pop(p)
---> 73             return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
     74         return _wrapped
     75     return _wrapper

TypeError: delete() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'
```

Can I not be able to delete entire index?
Is there any way to delete it without specifying the id of a particular one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, 'people' is not an index, it's a type. The index name is 'para'.
I don't know the python API, but your should try something like :

```
es.delete(index='para')
```

In this doc :
http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html

It is suggested to use something like :

```
es.indices.delete(index='para')
```